# Shell script to parse ip:port from a text file

Tags: bash, shell, text-parsing

I get daily a text file with ip:port, one per line, example:

```
11.22.33.44:80
22.33.44.55:8080
33.44.55.66:7777
```

I would like to parse the first ip and port in two different variables, then write them into another file, wait exceution of a program that use these variables, loop this cycle to pass all the ip:port to the file and execute program.

How can I do that?

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cat in.txt | sed -e "s/:/ /" | while read ip port
do
  echo $ip $port # or do something with it
done
```

Comment: working fine, even the code before the edit, thank you very much :)

Comment: My first version was no that nice :)

Comment: Sorry it's possibole to get 3 differents things? Like 11.22.33.44:80@blabla , I would like to get that blabla in other variable, thank you

Answer (score 5):

A pure bash solution:

```
while IFS=: read ip port; do
    echo $ip $port
done < in.txt
```

This has the advantage of allowing you to set variables inside the while loop that remain available after the loop completes.

Comment: Note that this is not just pure bash, but is also pure sh.

Comment: Some day, I will learn which features are bash extensions and which features are in the POSIX spec.

Comment: thank you for your solution, still using the over one because I use these variable into the loop